# How to send image to the salesforce soap service?

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I am using salesforce php tool kit to send data to my salesforce account. But I did not found any clue to send an image to the salsefoce with php. Can some one please give me an example how to do this?

Comment: what method are you using to send data?

Comment: At the moment I'm susing SforcePartnerClient but it really does not matter of you have SforceEnterpriceClient please let me know..

Comment: i mean what API method

Comment: I use normal create,delete, update, edit method as in this article(http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP)
But I did not found a way to send image rather than data

Comment: looks like its using a SQL like interface to read and write data, so do you know the field which accepts the image data?

Comment: It should be mapped with  the SF attachment object (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm). I assume it should be base64 type

Comment: you don't have to assume its written there `base64`

Comment: yes that's true. So do you have any ideas to implementation?\

Comment: ai machang ubata hithanna kammalida :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32267/discussion-between-ruwantha-and-devzer0)